# Swipe Table Cells overlapping cell content on swipe motion

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm using MGSwipeTableCell in swift, but have tried multiple other libraries, all resulting in the same problem.

Basically, I set up a custom cell class, of the type MGSwipeTableCell. I add some labels, etc, and this all works well. See code below for Cell Class Code.

```
import UIKit
import BTLabel
import MGSwipeTableCell

class MessageCell: MGSwipeTableCell {

let name = UILabel()
let contactTime = BTLabel()
let lineSeperator = UIView()

override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

}


required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
}


override func layoutSubviews() {

    super.layoutSubviews()

    self.backgroundColor = Styles().heyGreen()
    self.selectionStyle = .None

    name.frame = CGRectMake(self.bounds.width/10, self.bounds.height/5, self.bounds.width/10*7, self.bounds.height/10*5)
    name.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    name.font = Styles().FontBold(30)
    name.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    name.textAlignment = .Left
    self.addSubview(name)


    contactTime.frame = CGRectMake(self.bounds.width/10, self.bounds.height/10*7, self.bounds.width/10*7, self.bounds.height/10*2)
    contactTime.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    contactTime.font = Styles().FontBold(15)
    contactTime.textColor = Styles().heySelectedOverLay()
    contactTime.verticalAlignment = .Top
    contactTime.textAlignment = .Left
        self.addSubview(contactTime)

        lineSeperator.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.bounds.height - 1, self.bounds.width, 1)
        lineSeperator.backgroundColor = Styles().heySelectedOverLay()
        self.addSubview(lineSeperator)
    }

}
```

The cellForRowMethod is as follows in my tableviewcontroller.

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cellIdendifier: String = "MessageCell"

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdendifier) as! MessageCell!
    if cell == nil {
   tableView.registerClass(MessageCell.classForCoder(), forCellReuseIdentifier: cellIdendifier)

        cell = MessageCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: cellIdendifier)
    }

    cell.name.text = "heysup"
    cell.contactTime.text = "100 days"

    cell.delegate = self //optional

    //configure left buttons
    cell.leftButtons = [MGSwipeButton(title: "", icon: UIImage(named:"check.png"), backgroundColor: UIColor.greenColor())
        ,MGSwipeButton(title: "", icon: UIImage(named:"fav.png"), backgroundColor: UIColor.blueColor())]
    cell.leftSwipeSettings.transition = MGSwipeTransition.Rotate3D

    //configure right buttons
    cell.rightButtons = [MGSwipeButton(title: "Delete", backgroundColor: UIColor.redColor())
        ,MGSwipeButton(title: "More",backgroundColor: UIColor.lightGrayColor())]
    cell.rightSwipeSettings.transition = MGSwipeTransition.Rotate3D

    return cell
}
```

The problem lies in that this is how it looks when i swipe across.

[image]

I'm not sure where it's going wrong or what it's doing. I'm also not sure if it's because i'm adding the labels to the wrong layer? I remember in obj-c you used to add things to the cell view or something to that effect...

Any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually resolved this issue - i needed to add the labels to the contentView, not the actual view.

so the code should have been

```
self.contentView.addSubview(name)
```

for example, on the custom tableviewcell

Comment: Thanks Worked for me. Facing same issue